# Update linking path

Tags: root-access, security, privacy, native-library, folders

How do I add a new directory to linking path? Meaning add a directory to where the dynamic linker will look for shared libraries.

In Ubuntu you can create a .conf file under /etc/ld.so.conf.d and write the path name to the directory you want to be searched by the dynamic linker in that file and run ldconfig command afterwards to update it.

I am wondering if there is something similar under android.